# Updates to i18n translation files in Angular

Tags: angular, xliff, angular-i18n

I am currently in the process of adding en locale to an Angular App we are using at my company. After some thinking we decided to go with the Angular 5+ native i18n support.

From how I understand it however, everytime the translation file is generated with `ng xi18n --outputPath src/locale/ --locale en` a new file is created. This means, that every time a new i18n tag is added, the previous XLF file which already contains the old translations, needs to be merged with the new translations.

This seems highly bothersome, therefore my question: Is there a way such that the new trans-units are just appended to the already existing XLF file? Or is there already a tool which can merge these two together?

EDIT:
xliffmerge seems to be unmaintained and incompatible with latest Angular versions (> 12).
See answer by @daniel-sc for an option for latest Angular versions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edited answer**

You can use the [xliffmerge](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport) tool. It can merge translation files after you've added new translations in your html

Here is a [tutorial](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/wiki/Tutorial-for-using-xliffmerge-with-angular-cli) for angular

Basically after running your normal extract command you call xliffmerge and pass the language(s) for which you want to generate translation files

```
ng xi18n --outputPath src/locale/ --locale en && xliffmerge --profile xliffmerge.json en fr
```

You can specify a json config for the tool

```
{
  "xliffmergeOptions": {
  "srcDir": "src/locale",
  "genDir": "src/locale"
   }
}
```

**Original answer**

Try setting custom ids to your translations

https://angular.io/guide/i18n#set-a-custom-id-for-persistence-and-maintenance

```
<h1 i18n="@@introductionHeader">Hello i18n!</h1>
```

Nex time you run the extract command, it'll just add the new blocks but won't touch the existing ones

Btw I think going with the native option is a good choice, since the maintainer of the main alternative (ngx-translate) is actually working with the angular team on the native approach

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? I updated my question with the full command I am using. I also already use unique IDs, however when I rerun the command, there is a new file called messages.xlf which does not contain a single one of the existing translations.

Comment: @seBaka28 and where is your 'real' translation file? name/location?

Comment: messages.en.xlf is in src/locale/ - same location where the new messages.xlf is after generation

Comment: I edited my answer. I was actually so sure that the native tool could merge by default that I had not even tried (I'm right in the middle of it in my project!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this still the best approach for updating/merging new translations, especially when adding new html files (I am using Angular 10)?

Comment: @Ray Don't know, we haven't moved to angular 10 yet

Comment: @Ray The problem is that the tool [ngx-i18n-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-i18nsupport) seems to be no longer updated (the last update was two years ago). Therefore it uses things from i18n that are **deprecated** (e.g. `i18nFile`, `i18nFormat` and `i18nLocale`). It still works under Angular 11, but in the future this could become a problem. I haven't found a better option yet.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative/new solution (to the unmaintained ngx-i18nsupport) is https://github.com/daniel-sc/ng-extract-i18n-merge

After installing via

```bash
ng add ng-extract-i18n-merge
```

translations will be extracted *and merged* with the command:

```bash
ng extract-i18n
```

(Transparency: I created this library.)

Comment: Maybe add a comment that you are the creator of that library.

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks for making it!

Answer (score 0):

I Had some issue with previous solution : `ERROR: language [...] node_modules\@ngx-i18nsupport\ngx-i18nsupport\xliffmerge\xliffmerge" is not valid`

I used **xliffmerge** with **angular-cli** : https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport to extract/merge i18n. It generates for you the commands in `package.json` and the config for new task in `angular.json`. It keeps the context-groups and notes when merging.

I just had to change the default settings in `package.json` and `angular.json` for my chosen output-path `"src/locale"`.

Comment: @bergacat1 just follow the instructions to insall xliffmerge here : https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/tree/master/projects/xliffmerge. I will create a new npm scripts task which use ng build with the proper options.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ngx-i18nsupport-package will not be developed anymore we are now using [rvanbekkum.xliff-sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvanbekkum.xliff-sync) for this issue which works like a charm.